# Android: Exception at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismissInternal(DialogFragment.java:196)

Tags: android, exception, android-fragments, dialog, progress-bar

I have created a dialog fragment with a progress bar to display the upload state of some files in my app. I show the dialog in onStart(), at the same time I set a boolean to "true", so if the upload is interrupted or restarted due to a timeout the dialog first get dismissed then showed again. Without dismissing it first, a similar error appeared in onProgress() before.

The error I receive in my prodution app sometimes on some devices:

```
> java.lang.NullPointerException at
> android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismissInternal(DialogFragment.java:196)
> at
> android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismiss(DialogFragment.java:167)
> at foto.studio.OrderActivity$2.onStart(OrderActivity.java:373) at
> com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:325)
> at
> com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:138)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4827) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608) at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have highlighted the error in onStart():

```
client.post("http://www.edmondvarga.com/laborator/upload.php", params,
            new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2, Throwable arg3) {                       
                    if (arg0 == 0) {
                        System.out.println("Retrying Upload!");
                        sendZip();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgress(int position, int length) {
                    try {
                        ((PreloaderDialog) progressDialog).passValues(
                                position, length);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    // Show preloader dialog
                    if (preloaderOn) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    //====================ERROR AT THIS LINE=================
                    progressDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "preloader");

                    preloaderOn = true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] arg2) {
                    System.out.println("Success!");
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Multumim pentru Comanda!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish(); 
                }
            });
```

Why am I gettin NPE at: "progressDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "preloader");" ?

Thanks!

Comment: where do you toggle `preloaderOn` to false, in the code and also it is asynchronous and you create a new instance anytime,maybe you might be having double instances etc etc, have you checked that too

Comment: @Elltz - I initialise "preloaderOn" with the value 'false' at the beginning of the activty. Once the preloader is on, I need it to be true in order to avoid the  the fragment to be displayed again. Or am I missing something?